# Angular7+, *ngFor X amount of items per row, best practice

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

I started some months ago to use Angular for my projects and I have a situation where I need some advice.

I'm using Bootstrap4 and I need to create a row for each 3 items that are stored in an array. The array has a dynamic size, so if my array has 21 items I need to create 7 rows with 3 items per row.

I found many questions about this topic but I don't know which solution to use.

The best solutions so far:

1. Using multiple ngIf*:
   https://riptutorial.com/angular2/example/32251/-ngfor-x-amount-of-items-per-row
2. Split the original array in a multi-dimensional array and use *ngFor 2 times:
   https://medium.com/@miki995/angular-6-bootstrap-4-row-columns-same-height-8be5bdb53099

Did somebody used a solution? Or there is something better that was introduced with the latest versions of Angular?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question? You want to have rows each containing 3 items? Just use `col-4` for each item.

Comment: I will adapt my question, but if I have 21 items in my array. I want to create a new row for each 3 items.

Comment: Again, just use `col-4` for each item. https://www.bootply.com/o7m8Xv0eiA

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have an array with a dynamic size, let's say: `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]` and you want to display this array in an table with 3 columns rights ?

Comment: @Eastrall, yes. In your case a row will have 1, 2 , 3 and the second row: 4, 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basicaly, you have an array with a dynamic size, let's say: `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`.
What you actually want to do, is somehow have an array that contains one or more arrays of N values like: `[["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5"]]`.

To do so, you can use this snippet:

```js
function groupArray<T>(data: Array<T>, n: number): Array<T[]> {
    let group = new Array<T[]>();
​
    for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (i >= n && i % n === 0)
            j++;
        group[j] = group[j] || [];
        group[j].push(data[i])
    }
​
    return group;
}
```

Now, to use it, simply call it like this:

```js
var arrayOfData: string[] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var group = groupArray(arrayOfData, 3);

console.log(group); // displays: ["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5"]
```

In angular, you can now, make a `*ngFor` on the `group` array to build the rows, and then another `*ngFor` to build the columns.
Be careful on the last array thought, you might not have the correct length depending on the size of you original array. You will need to "complete" the last array with empty values or whatever you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Eastral, for typescript,  replace "var" for "let" and remove "function" in your function

Comment: YEs. this is a solution. It is similar with the point 2 from my question. I will let you know if I will use this approach.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to use a different approach. If you use [bootstrap flexbox Wrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#wrap), and with fixed width, you can still use a single `*ngFor` and the result will get generated with "line-breaks" after every 3 items (if you force it to fit 3 items in a row).

So Something like this:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap" style="width: 300px">
  <div *ngFor="let item of myArrayOfItems style="width: 10px">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

That way it is much easier to extend the functionality for possible future shorter rows too (for instance in a responsive, mobile-friendly UI)

Comment: This is intersting. But I don't know what to say about the fixed width.

Comment: it it suits the problem better, you can still use a width percentage instead I belive.

Comment: Did you try this solution with percentages?

Comment: It doesn't work how I want. I will go with the solution 1

Answer (score -1):

You can use lodash to creates an array of elements split into groups the length of size.
_.chunk(array, [size=1])

Or use

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
let chunk_size = 3; //no. of elements you want to print in single row
let chunkArray = arr.map(function(e, i) {
return i % chunk_size === 0 ? arr.slice(i, i + chunk_size) : null;
})
.filter(function(e) {
return e;
});


<div class="row" *ngFor="let data of chunkArray ">
<div class ="col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of data">
{{item.name}}
</div>
</div>
```